# NameError: global name 'parts' is not defined

Tags: python

I have the following 3 files:

The following file in folder lib

lib/StringSplitting.py:

```
def type1():
    try:
        name1     = parts[1] 
        something = parts[2]
        x = 0
    except IndexError, e:
        x = None

    if x is None:
        print 'well something went wrong'
```

I also have `lib/__init__.py` which is empty.

Then I have the main file

testing.py

```
#!usr/bin/python

from lib import StringSplitting

data = "some random string separated by spaces "

global parts
parts = data.split(" ")

StringSplitting.type1()

print something
```

Because I have multiple ways of separating a string I need to use different functions within StringSplitting.

Now the error that I want to resolve is:

```
NameError: global name 'parts' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

globals are only global to their own module, not across the Python interpreter.

Pass in the `parts` name as a function parameter instead:

```
StringSplitting.type1(parts)
```

where the `type1()` function has been redefined to accept a parameter:

```
def type1(parts):
```

Note that the `global` keyword only has any effect when used in a *function*; it tells the Python compiler that a name in a function is to be assigned to globally, not locally. Names at the module level are *already* global. The `global parts` line in `testing.py` is a no-op, it does nothing, and can be removed altogether.

Comment: Absolutely. Also remove the 'global parts' line from testing.py